# Shopify Api for products details updating using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, shopify

I am working with Shopify app for product details update by PHP in Shopify so anyone can please help me which API used for products details update in Shopify.

These following are details which I needs to update:

1) Products Price

2) Stock Availability

3) Products SKU

4) Products Variants

I found the method from https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product#index
which is below

Update a product, reordering the product variants

PUT /admin/products/#{id}.json

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 632910392,
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 457924702
      },
      {
        "id": 39072856
      },
      {
        "id": 49148385
      },
      {
        "id": 808950810
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But how to use above code in my following function:

```
public function post_one($arrData){
        return $this->call('POST', '/admin/products.json', $arrData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are updating a product/variant/anything in Shopify, you are required to do a PUT call rather than a POST call. POST is used to create something afresh.

Replace your function with the following. Here, the URL is in `PUT /admin/products/#{id}.json` format. Also note that, final URL must be like the following - `https://{shopify-store}.myshopify.com/admin/....`

```
public function put_one($arrData){
   return $this->call('PUT', '/admin/products/632910392.json', $arrData);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? I think that the OP might benefit from an explanation of `PUT` vs `POST`

Comment: Agreed. Updating.

Comment: Hey Hymmz thanks a lot for your kind reply but can you plz let me know how can i pass my json arrey in put method because i got your ans and you tell me used put method instant of post method but can you plz let me know how i can pass below json array using put method. There is no mention for how to pass this json to shopify.
{
  "product": {
    "id": 632910392,
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 457924702
      },
      {
        "id": 39072856
      },
      {
        "id": 49148385
      },
      {
        "id": 808950810
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @Tarun.. Your `$arrData` will be `{ "product": { "id": 632910392, "variants": [ { "id": 457924702 }, { "id": 39072856 }, { "id": 49148385 }, { "id": 808950810 } ] } }`

Comment: Thanks let me check

Answer (score 2):

If you are only modifying a single variant at a time, I highly recommend using the ProductVariant endpoint:

https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product_variant#update

If you use the Product endpoint to update a single variant, you could unintentionally destroy the rest of the variants if you aren't careful.

Comment: OP is looking to reorder the variants. It's the only way for reordering.

Comment: According to the OP, he is trying to update the following details:

"1) Products Price

2) Stock Availability

3) Products SKU

4) Products Variants"

The text `Update a product, reordering the product variants` is just copied from the API docs.